# How do I get a list of users who liked my "post" using Facebook graph API?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to access user-names from the API . I am only able to access the number of likes and not the list of people who liked it .
I tried doing this -

```
def get_post_likes(post):
   mylikes=[]
   try:
     likes=graph.get_connections(post['id'],connection_name='likes')
     print (post['message'])
     #print(likes['data'])
     mylikes = get_all_pages(likes)
   except:
     pass 
   return mylikes

def get_all_pages(posts):
   allposts=[]
   allposts = posts['data']
   while(1):
      try:
         next_page_url=posts['paging']['next']  #get url for next page
      except KeyError:
         break
      posts = requests.get(next_page_url).json()
      allposts += posts['data']
   return allposts
```

But like['data'] is empty , although none of my posts have 0 likes .
Even in the graph API explorer I am not able to access names.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about a page post? You need to use a page access token now to get any kind of personal user information in that context.

Comment: I am talking about my own posts i.e. from my username

Comment: i guess it is not possible for privacy reasons then

Comment: Guess you could probably get it for friends that are also using your app, but for others - nope.